# one mysql query getting, per each row, the average of the previous three rows

Tags: mysql

i have something like this:

```
id     | value
---------------
201311 | 10
201312 | 15
201401 | 20
201402 | 5
201403 | 17
```

and i need a result like this:

```
201311 | NULL or 0
201312 | 3.3     // 10/3
201401 | 8.3     // (15+10)/3
201402 | 15      // (20+15+10)/3
201403 | 13.3    // (5+20+15)/3
```

So far, i got to the point where i can get the AVG of the last three previous rows like this:

```
select AVG(c.value) FROM (select b.value from table as b where b.id < 201401 order by b.id DESC LIMIT 3) as c
```

passing the id manually. I'm not able to do it for each id.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

thanks a lot.

regards

Comment: you want the result like that but why your where clause b.id < 201401. Please give the valid result. And where is the NULL or 0 comes from? 201311 got value 10 even you take average it will not make it 0

Comment: i put 201401 because i'm not able to pass each id to that query. the NULL or 0 is because i need the average of the 3 previous rows

Comment: thanks @Strawberry, fixed the little typo :D

Comment: Then in 201312 why instead of (10+0)/2 you put 10/1? Is not we take average from '3 previous' rows?

Comment: you're definetely right, but i will discard all those "uncomplete" results, so it doesn't matter... but i understand i created confusion, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got to this now:

```
SELECT a.id, (select AVG(b.value) FROM table as b where b.id < a.id AND str_to_date(CONCAT(b.id,'01'), '%Y%m%d') >= DATE_SUB(str_to_date(CONCAT(a.id,'01'), '%Y%m%d'), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) FROM `table` as a WHERE 1
```

But i'm quite sure there should be a better/cleaner solution

Comment: just trying to use the same method in sql fiddle. rofl. But why you need to limit the date again instead of just LIMIT?

Comment: apparently LIMIT is the last thing to be run, so it's ignored during the AVG calculation :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write a stored procedure, use a cursor, iterate through the table and populate a new table using the values calculated in your cursor loop. If you need help with writing out the cursor loop, just drop a comment and I can get you an example.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, a SELECT query is essentially a batch process, whereas the info you want requires iteration over the table in a specific order, hence the need for a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id,coalesce(b.value,0) from test a left outer join
(select a.id, sum(b.value)/3 as value from
(select @row:=@row+1 as rownum,id,value from test,(select @row:=0)r) a,
(select @row1:=@row1+1 as rownum,id,value from test,(select @row1:=0)r) b
where b.rownum in (a.rownum-1,a.rownum-2,a.rownum-3)
group by a.rownum) b
on a.id=b.id;
```